# Maui Blazor Webview

Tags: maui-blazor

Hello updating to the last version of maui with blazor web view give me this error:

> System.Exception: 'Handler not found for view Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui.BlazorWebView.'

here my init code:

```
   var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        //.RegisterBlazorMauiWebView()
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        });

    builder.Services.AddBlazorWebView();
```

TargetFrameworks:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows')) and '$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Full'">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041</TargetFrameworks>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should update

```
builder.Services.AddBlazorWebView();
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
```

Comment: I just brought a MAUI-Blazor app from Windows to Mac, and when I try to build, I get an error that this extension method can't be found: error CS1061: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddMauiBlazorWebView' and no accessible extension method 'AddMauiBlazorWebView' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: And to clarify, it was building and running fine on Windows. The error seems to be when running on Mac targeting Mac Catalyst.

Comment: Further update: I undid your suggestion (AddMauiBlazorWebView -> AddBlazorWebView) and compilation works, but the app terminates immediately with the error from the OP. So, looks to me like a problem with the library version?